# Arduino String memory allocation

Tags: string, memory-usage, memory

When a String variable is declared and modified inside a function, where does it go? To the **heap**(as string declaration is a part of dynamic memory allocation) or to the **stack**(as it is a part of function)? And is the space regained after the function goes out of the scope?
For example

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.println(foo("def"));
  while(1);
}

String foo(String arg1)
{
 String test = "abc";
 test = test + arg1;
 return test;
}
```

So, in this case, the variable "test" is declared in stack or heap? And this space is regained at the end or not?

**Modified:**
What if inside loop variable is declared like below?

```
String foo_test = F("def");
Serial.println(foo(foo_test));
```

In this case what will be the status of variables?

Comment: There is the `String` object, and then there is the character data referenced by that object. They don't live together.

Comment: It compiled fine and showed the output too. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @EdgarBonet    you mean to say that string object will reside in stack and the char data reference will stay in heap? Pardon for misunderstanding in previous comment.

Comment: The string object may reside in the function's stack, in the caller's stack, or in CPU registers. That's a matter of compiler optimization. For a simplified mental picture, you may assume it's in the function's stack. Everything should work “as if” that's the case.

Comment: @EdgarBonet     @Mikael@Michel Please see the modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent question to illustrate the amount of string copying and heap operations (malloc/free) going on when using the Arduino String class.

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.println(foo("def"));
  while(1);
}
```

The compiler will generate loop() something like this:

```
void loop()
{
  // String literal is stored in program memory. Needs to be copied
  // to temporary variable. This is done before main() is called.
  static const char temp0[4] PROGMEM = "def";
  static const char temp1[4];
  copy_from_program_memory(temp1, temp0);

  // The parameter to the call to foo() is actually a temporary String 
  // variable constructed from the string literal. Storage is allocated 
  // on the heap and the assigned from the value of the string literal.
  String temp2;
  temp2.constructor(temp1);

  // The return value of the call to foo() is a String that is passed
  // to Serial.println(). This is also a temporary String variable. 
  String temp3;
  temp3.constructor(foo(temp2));
  Serial.println(temp3);

  // The String class destructor has to be called for the temporary
  // String variable so that the string values on heap are deallocated.
  temp2.destructor();
  temp3.destructor();
}
```

Note that each call to the constructor involves allocating and copying data to the heap.

```
String foo(String arg1)
{
 String test = "abc";
 test = test + arg1;
 return test;
}
```

The function foo() needs to copy strings several times to perform the string concatenation. The operator+ will require an intermediate String copy.

Cheers!

PS: For more details please see the assembly listing below with the calls to String member functions. The compiler reduces inline member functions and reuses temporary local variables. Also the call to foo() is inlined. The member function reserve() is part of the constructor.

```
00000198 <main>:
 1de:   60 df           rcall   .-320       ; 0xa0 <String::reserve(unsigned int)>
 1fc:   50 d2           rcall   .+1184      ; 0x69e <strcpy>
 212:   46 df           rcall   .-372       ; 0xa0 <String::reserve(unsigned int)>
 230:   36 d2           rcall   .+1132      ; 0x69e <strcpy>
 248:   62 df           rcall   .-316       ; 0x10e <String::operator=(String const&)>
 26a:   1a df           rcall   .-460       ; 0xa0 <String::reserve(unsigned int)>
 27e:   0f d2           rcall   .+1054      ; 0x69e <strcpy>
 28e:   3f df           rcall   .-386       ; 0x10e <String::operator=(String const&)>
 294:   60 df           rcall   .-320       ; 0x156 <String::~String()>
 29a:   5d df           rcall   .-326       ; 0x156 <String::~String()>
 2a0:   5a df           rcall   .-332       ; 0x156 <String::~String()>
```

Bottom-line is that the String class uses a lot of instruction cycles and memory, and there is a potential risk of heap fragmentation and allocation failure.

Comment: I would expect `copy_from_program_memory(temp1, temp0);` to be done only once, by `__do_copy_data()`, from the C runtime.

Comment: Yes, that would also make temp1 static. Should correct that.

Comment: This is a nice explanation. Can you please suggest some good reference or articles to this memory issue?

Comment: Please see https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Comment: See also http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html

Comment: And last the source https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.h and https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp.

Answer (score 4):

The truth here turns out to be a bit more complicated than the other answers express. **There's more than one implementation of the Arduino String library, and some are better than others.** Which one you get depends on which board you deploy to.

The newer code handles strings a whole lot more efficiently, particularly in terms of memory usage, and changes the whole dynamic around the answer to this question.

Compare the *original* version of the Arduino String library, [the one for AVR](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WString.cpp), to [the version for the ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/WString.cpp).
*(As of writing this answer, these were [this snapshot](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/c270eaabf4b7e85b0cfbb96c57817af5995b5ad8/cores/arduino/WString.cpp) and [this snapshot](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/698ffc34980191ab422918e3aa22ea90b6596766/cores/esp8266/WString.cpp), respectively.)*

Looking in particular at the functions like `changeBuffer` you can see that the ESP version contains something called "SSO" ("Small String Optimization") added with [this PR here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/pull/5690). Basically, for small strings—small enough to fit in the structure would otherwise be used to track the string buffer on the heap—it'll just store the string in that space (in the String object itself) instead.

In practice, this means strings smaller than 12 characters don't require memory allocation; they're stored on the stack inside the String object.

This is a pretty huge deal if you push around a lot of tiny strings, like in the example listed in the question. It means that the code works about as efficiently as you might hope, without problematic side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

The string is an instance of an object, high likely keeping the administration like the offset and size (unless it is implemented as a 0-delimited string).
This is a local variable and will be stored on the stack and will be nicely removed after finishing the function.

The characters itself ("abc" ...) will be stored on the heap since this needs to be dynamic. This data will be freed by the string object after returning from the function and possibly when needed to relocate the string.

Normally a string instance will keep some memory allocated, when it is increased (or increased too much) the string content will be copied. This all happens in heap and 'holes' in the heap can occur by this.

That's why in a memory/time critical process it's best to allocate the string before hand, of course this is only possible if you know the (maximum) string size.

Comment: You said this is a local variable and will be stored in stack. Did you mean to say variable "test" will be stored in stack?But when string manipulation occurs i.e test += arg1; isn't it that the size of test will increase in heap or is it stack?

Comment: As Edgar already wrote, there are two items: the instance (keeping the administration), this is probably the pointer and possible the size of the string; this will be kept in stack. The memory allocation will never change. However, the characters itself are stored on the heap since this will change. When you add a character, depending on the implementation, possibly the whole string will be copied from one heap space to another location in the heap (using one more byte), and the pointer (stored in the stack) is pointing to the new allocated space in the heap.

Comment: Also you can use the F(" ..." ) way, this puts the fixed strings in flash memory (of course for altering strings this is not possible).

Comment: Yes, Explanation is good.